# showing results as 'Undefined', instead of expected output in text field

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I want to populate values into 4 text fields based on the value given in the input field. when control comes out of the input field, a function getcredentials() is called which in turn calls a python code. python code retrieves the 4 required values from an excel sheet and returns the result as a dictionary. I have tried to set those 4 values from the result dictionary in the following way. please correct me.

script :

```
<script>
      function getcredentials() {
        var x = document.index.AWSID.value;
         console.log(x)
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.index.APPUSERNAME.value  = this.responseText['AppUsername'];
      document.index.APPPASSWORD.value  = this.responseText['AppPassword'];
      document.index.RDPUSERNAME.value  = this.responseText['RdpUsername'];
      document.index.RDPPASSWORD.value  = this.responseText['RdpPassword'];
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', 'getcredentials', true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    /*xhttp.send(x);*/
    xhttp.send("x="+encodeURIComponent(x));
       }
    </script>
```

python code :

```
def getCredentials(request):
AwsId = request.POST.get('x')
result = {'RdpUsername' : 'Opsadmin', 
          'RdpPassword' : '--C0nt@1ns^Ph3n%l@l@n1n3--', 
          'AppUsername' : 'Admin', 
          'AppPassword' : 'M@St3r..CRM'}
result['RdpPassword'] = result['RdpPassword'] + AwsId[-5:]
result['AppPassword'] = result['AppPassword'] + AwsId[0:3]
response = HttpResponse(result)
return response
```

Comment: Hi, you are returning normal string or json from backend? Also , put `alert(this.responseText)` see what it print .

Comment: Hi Swati, I have output in the 'result' dictionary and have passed the result to HttpResponse and returned the response. alert(this.responseText) is printing keys of the result as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `JsonResponse(result)` rather than `HttpResponse`. Something like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getCredentials(request):
    AwsId = request.POST.get('x')
    result = ...
    response = JsonResponse(result)
    return response
```